# I have already installed Pyaudio but still visual studio code is showing please check installation of PyAudio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, attributes

I have already installed the PyAudio module but Visual Studio Code is showing an error:

> please check installation of PyAudio

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please check and see if you pip installed PyAudio to the same version of python vscode is using.  It would probably be better to install a virtual environment in your project folder and use that to avoid confusion.  Open a terminal in vscode. Then
Python3 -m venv venv

source venv/bin/activate

pip install PyAudio

Although this step is a little different if using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt means it can't find the package in the environment you are using. After you select the environment, remember to activate the terminal(Ctrl+Shift+`) before install the package. Otherwise, you would install the package in the wrong environment(wrong place), although you installed the package you still can't find it.

It is recommended to create a virtual environment as Charles Wilson said. you can refer to [python environment official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for more information.